# I am confused with the argument in an event function

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a code for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/x0k5dx8w/8/

From my understanding:
The event handler (eg; addEventListener) passes the event object into the parameters of the invoked function.

```
(eg; document.getElementbyId("idname").addEventListener("click", function(eventobj),
```

is essentialy saying

```
document.getElementbyId("id").addEventListener("click", function(idname));
```

Now I am confused with two things, what is the difference between not giving your event function parameter a name vs giving it a name?

and lastly,
why is that you cannot do:

```
function eventFunc() {
    var object1 = document.getElementById("object1");
    if( object1.target =..... ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. `addEventListener` is *not* "the event handler" - it's a function you use to register *another* function as an event handler.

Comment: The parameter to the callback is an Event, not the element on which the event occurred.

Comment: Wow that really clears things alot, but since it is an "Event" now, what does it mean?

Comment: You can log the event to the console... that will tell you what it means, and more importantly, what it contains: `console.log(eventObj)`

Comment: @MatthewFrancis you should check out MDN, Mozilla's documentation for the web. It's a wonderful resource. I've linked several pages in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you posted is not, well, valid. Let's review how to handle an event.

An [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) is a function that takes an [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object as parameter:

```
function handleClick(event) {
  let elementClicked = event.target;
  console.log('You clicked', elementClicked);
}
```

The [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) has several useful properties and methods. `target` is the most commonly accessed, but `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` are also important to know about.

To attach a listener to an element, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
let someElement = document.querySelector('button')
someElement.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

To remove it, use `removeEventListener`, passing *the same function object given to `addEventListener`* (not a copy, wrapper or inline function: the SAME function object):

```
someElement.removeEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

For future reference, check out Mozilla's MDN (where all the links in this answer come from), it's a fantastic resource.

Cheers!

Comment: Just a word to the OP: this answer contains EMCA 6 syntax (e.g. `let`), which you may not have seen before and only works in the latest versions of most major browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting confused between the DOM element ("idname") and the event object.

Your statement

```
document.getElementbyId("idname").addEventListener("click", function(eventobj)
```

is essentialy saying

```
document.getElementbyId("id").addEventListener("click", function(idname));
```

is wrong on at least two counts:

1) "document.getElementbyId("idname")" is not the same as "document.getElementbyId("id")" . "id" and "idname" are two different IDs. They can't represent the same element.

2) ".addEventListener("click", function(idname))". Idname (i.e. the DOM element) does not get passed to the function. An Event object gets passed to the function.

Likewise you can't do your suggestion of

```
function eventFunc(){
var object1 = document.getElementById("object1");
if(object1.target =.....)
//do something
}
```

because "object" is a DOM element, not an event object.

See a working example of the event model here:
https://jsfiddle.net/obqmazzs/3/

See also some fairly comprehensive documentation at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp

Answer (score 0):

the first variable in a function such as this is the "event object" whcih is not the object the event happened on, but rather a collection of data related to the event that occurred.

example:

> function(event){
>    console.log(event.target)
>   }

if you bind this event to say, a div on click, the event 'event' is the click that occurred and any data related to it.

event.target will a listof everything that was clicked on (the div, the divs parent, the body, the document)

or event.preventDefault() will stop all the default actions associated with an event  (example, a link click going to a different page)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking somethings.

```
document.getElementbyId("idname").addEventListener("click", function(eventobj)
```

is not the same that

```
document.getElementbyId("id").addEventListener("click", function(idname));
```

When you add an event listener it returns an event type when it raises, not the original object. This event type has some information about the original object but also has many other properties.

You can get more info about event type here: [Events](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp)

1º There is not a difference between set a parameter or not. When you need information about the event you can pass a parameter to the function to get that information (For example to know how fires the event), but if you do not need any information you can just avoid it(For example to show an alert message when you click a button).

2º You can not do that because object1 has not property "target". That property is from event type.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you, but how do you see the ifnormation being displayed through the event object?

Comment: You can get all information of an event making reference to it like this:

`document.getElementbyId("idname").addEventListener("click", function(eventobj){
    console.log(eventobj.timeStamp); //It returns the time in milliseconds at which the event was created
     console.log(eventobj.target);     //Returns the element that triggered the event
});`

The name of the event variable is irrelevant you can choose whatever you like. Check the link above to see all properties and methods that events have.